# How do I return NULL values after performing a LEFT JOIN in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I've created a LEFT JOIN in LINQ. How do I get my query to return my nullable values?

```
+------+------+------+
| c1   |  c2  |  c3  |
|------+------+------|
|  x1  |  y1  | z1   |
|  x2  |  y2  | null |
|  x3  |  y3  | z1   |
+------+------+------+
```

Above is basically the SQL table returned after LEFT JOIN as expected

However using LINQ:

````
        var query = 
                    ```
                    into temp
                    from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                       ```,
                       ```,
                       Column3 = (int?)t.ColumnNo
                    };
````

Debugger barks at me for `Column3` for:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: `t` is null right?  So you'd want to do `(int?)t.?ColumnNo`?

Comment: It seems to me that you haven't posted valid C# code. Could you give us a [mcve]? That would be your source as valid C# (rather than, or in addition to, the table of data) and then you could provide a query that is valid C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your `DefaultIfEmpty()`, the resulting `t` can be null. And of course you can't get the `ColumnNo` from a null object.

The quick solution would be to use the [null conditional operator:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
Column3 = t?.ColumnNo; // assuming ColumnNo is already an int? otherwise cast to int?
```

Which has the same effect as:

```
Column3 = (t.ColumnNo != null) t.ColumnNo : null;
```

The [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) as others suggested won't work:

```
Column3 = (t.c3 ?? 0)
```

if `t` equals null, you can't get `t.c3`, and thus can't check if `t.c3` equals null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `??` to set a default value if the column value is null:

````
 select new{
               ```,
               ```,
               Column3 = (t.c3 ?? 0) // if null set its value to zero
           };
````

Comment: Isn't the issue that `t` is null, not that `c3` is null?

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = (from PM in DataContext.table1
              join U in DataContext.table2 on PM.Id equals U.Id into obj1
              from U1 in obj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  Professions = U1.ProfessionName // If null
              });
```

You can use DefaultIfEmpty and use that object to get the column so you can get null values in column.

Comment: They are already using `DefaultIfEmpty()`.  As with the OP, wouldn't `U1` be null?